# How do I write $\omega_1^{\omega}$ in a Cantor Normal form?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I would like to ask about an example.

Write an ordinal in a Cantor Normal form: $\omega_1^{\omega}$.
The problem is, that I absolutely don't know how to apply a theory on this example. I have not found any materials which would explain some examples. I would be pleased if somebody try to explain it me here. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know how to write $\omega_1$ in Cantor normal form?

Comment: Did you already read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Cantor_normal_form), e.g. Beyond $\varepsilon_0$ there isn't much point to Cantor normal forms, it seems to me.

Comment: $\omega_1 = \omega ^{\omega_1}$. So it will be $\omega^{\omega_1^{\omega}}$? :)

Comment: Yes I did. You thing that every ordinal number, which has  a bigger value than $\epsilon_0$ is easy to write in a Cantor normal form, because it is just $\omega$ to the power of this number, because all of them have got a beautiful property like $\epsilon_0$: $\omega^{\epsilon_0} = \epsilon_0$? :))

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your advice and comments I thing that I am a little bit cleverer now. If for every ordinal number $\omega_n$, bigger than $\epsilon_0$, pays: $\omega^{\omega_n} = \omega_n$ and $\omega_1^{\omega}$ is bigger than $\epsilon_0$, does it mean, that $\omega_1^{\omega}$ is in the Cantor form written as $\omega^{\omega_1^{\omega}}$?

Thanks